# Apache Kafka transaction data flow

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, distributed-transactions

I'm reading about Kafka transaction data flow and one thing that's not clear to me is what happens after the coordinator sends WriteTxnMarkerRequest to leaders of each partition. I understand that the request makes the leader brokers write a control message to the log, but do they respond to the coordinator with an acknowledgement? In their original design document, https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Jqy_GjUGtdXJK94XGsEIK7CP1SnQGdp2eF0wSw9ra8/edit#heading=h.bgy58z5pyzw7, the data flow diagram doesn't seem like the coordinator waits for the acknowledgement. If that's the case, does it just write a final commit or abort message to the transaction log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition leaders in a transaction do indeed respond to the coordinator once it has appended a control message to the log. This is according to a confluence page https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka.